# Use boost::hash_value to define std::hash in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, hash, stdhash

Is there an easy way to do the following with C++11 & Boost:

- use the standard definitions of `std::hash` whenever available from `<functional>`
- use `boost::hash_value` to define `std::hash` in those cases where `std::hash` is missing but `boost::hash_value` is available in `<boost/functional/hash.hpp>`.

For example:

- `std::hash<std::vector<bool>>` should come from the standard library,
- `std::hash<std::vector<unsigned>>` should be implemented with `boost::hash_value`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12753997/743214

Answer (score 5):

The first idea that comes to mind is to use SFINAE and try `std::hash<>` if possible and otherwise use `boost::hash_value()`, like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>

struct my_struct_0 {
    std::string s;
};

template <typename T>
struct has_std_hash_subst { typedef void type; };

template <typename T, typename C = void>
struct has_std_hash : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct has_std_hash<
    T,
    typename has_std_hash_subst<decltype( std::hash<T>()(T()) ) >::type
> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
static typename std::enable_if<has_std_hash<T>::value, size_t>::type
make_hash(const T &v)
{
    return std::hash<T>()(v);
}

template <typename T>
static typename std::enable_if<(!has_std_hash<T>::value), size_t>::type
make_hash(const T &v)
{
    return boost::hash_value(v);
}

int main()
{
    make_hash(std::string("Hello, World!"));
    make_hash(my_struct_0({ "Hello, World!" }));
}
```

Unfortunately, there is always a default specialization of `std::hash` that triggers `static_assert` failure. This may not be the case with other libraries but it is the case with GCC 4.7.2 (see `bits/functional_hash.h:60`):

```
  /// Primary class template hash.
  template<typename _Tp>
    struct hash : public __hash_base<size_t, _Tp>
    {
      static_assert(sizeof(_Tp) < 0,
                    "std::hash is not specialized for this type");
      size_t operator()(const _Tp&) const noexcept;
    };
```

So the above SFINAE approach doesn't work — `static_assert` in there is a show-stopper. Therefore, you cannot really determine when `std::hash` is available.

Now, this does not really answer your question but might come handy — it is possible to do this trick the other way around — check for Boost implementation first and only then fall back to `std::hash<>`. Consider the below example that uses `boost::hash_value()` if it is available (i.e. for `std::string` and `my_struct_0`) and otherwise uses `std::hash<>` (i.e. for `my_struct_1`):

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>

struct my_struct_0 {
    std::string s;
};

struct my_struct_1 {
    std::string s;
};

namespace boost {
size_t hash_value(const my_struct_0 &v) {
    return boost::hash_value(v.s);
}
}

namespace std {
template <>
struct hash<my_struct_1> {
    size_t operator()(const my_struct_1 &v) const {
        return std::hash<std::string>()(v.s);
    }
};

}

template <typename T>
struct has_boost_hash_subst { typedef void type; };

template <typename T, typename C = void>
struct has_boost_hash : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct has_boost_hash<
    T,
    typename has_boost_hash_subst<decltype(boost::hash_value(T()))>::type
> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
static typename std::enable_if<has_boost_hash<T>::value, size_t>::type
make_hash(const T &v)
{
    size_t ret = boost::hash_value(v);
    std::cout << "boost::hash_value(" << typeid(T).name()
              << ") = " << ret << '\n';
    return ret;
}

template <typename T>
static typename std::enable_if<(!has_boost_hash<T>::value), size_t>::type
make_hash(const T &v)
{
    size_t ret = std::hash<T>()(v);
    std::cout << "std::hash(" << typeid(T).name()
              << ") = " << ret << '\n';
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    make_hash(std::string("Hello, World!"));
    make_hash(my_struct_0({ "Hello, World!" }));
    make_hash(my_struct_1({ "Hello, World!" }));
}
```

Hope it helps.

UPDATE: Perhaps you could use the hack described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753997/check-if-type-is-hashable) as pointed out by @ChristianRau and make the first SFINAE approach work! Though it is very dirty :)

Comment: The intent with hash_value is that it is found by ADL in the namespace of the argument so we shouldn't provide specializations in namespace boost.  The exception to this rule is the specializations boost provides for std::vector etc - the standard does not allow adding them to namespace std, so boost adds them to namespace boost.

Answer (score 1):

My answer might not be correct, but I will try to explain why I think that the answer is no.

I don't think that `std::hash<T>` and `boost:hash<T>` can be used interchangeably, so I've tried hiding object creation (even if this is not perfect solution), and return their result, which is size_t. Method should be of course chosen at compile time, so function dispatch is what comes to my mind, sample code:

```
template <typename T>
size_t createHash(const T& t, false_type)
{
    return boost::hash<T>()(t);
}

template <typename T>
size_t createHash(const T& t, true_type)
{   
    return std::hash<T>()(t);
}

template<typename T>
size_t createHash(const T& t)
{
    return createHash<T>(t, std::is_XXX<T>::type());
}


int main() 
{
    vector<unsigned> v; v.push_back(1);
    auto h1 = createHash(v);
    cout << " hash: " << h1;
    //hash<vector<unsigned> > h2;
}
```

The idea of this code is simple: if you can construct type of type `std::hash<T>`, choose second implementation, if not - choose first one.

If the first implementation is chosen, code compiles without a problem, you can check it by using fe. `std::is_array<T>::type()` in a wrapper function, which is of course not true, so boost::hash implementation will be choosed. However, if you use a trait which will return `true_t` for a `vector<unsigned>`, like fe. `std::is_class<T>::type()` then the compiler will report "C++ Standard doesn't provide...", which is a result of a `static_assert`.

For this to work, we would need to force compiler to return `true_t` if a type is really constructible (it doesn't fail static_assert) and `false_t` if it doesn't. However, I don't think there is a possibility to do that.