# How can I create a template class that can choose special container for T?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

How can I create a template class that can understand if type `T` is hashable or not, and if it is then use `std::unodered_set` to collect elements of type T?. Otherwise, I want it to use `std::set`.

This class have the same simple methods as above `sets` such as `insert(), find()` and so on.

```
template<class T>
class MySet {
public:
    MySet() {}
    bool find() {
    //some code here
```

I check if type has `operator()` to get information about its "hashability". For this purpose I use the following construction, which I found on this site:

```
template<typename T>
class HasHash {
    typedef char one;
    typedef long two;

    template<typename C>
    static one test(decltype(&C::operator()));

    template<typename C>
    static two test(...);

public:
    enum {
        value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(size_t)
    };
};
```

And get is hashable or not (true or false) by typing:

```
HasHash<HashableType>::value
```

There is no way for me to use boost library.

Comment: Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753997/check-if-type-is-hashable) solve your problem?

Comment: I have seen this post and I have already solved that part of my problem. The question is how to create class that will be using different `sets` for different types.

Comment: How about `std::conditional_t<is_hashable_v<T>, std::unordered_set<T>, std::set<T>>`?

Comment: Looks good, thank you! I'll try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a full working example, assuming you are using `std::hash`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <typename...> using void_t = void;

template <typename, typename = void>
struct is_hashable : std::false_type { };
template <typename T>
struct is_hashable<T, void_t<decltype(std::hash<T>{})>> : std::true_type { };

template <typename T>
using set = typename std::conditional<
  is_hashable<T>::value, std::unordered_set<T>, std::set<T>
>::type;

template <typename T> void test() { cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; }

struct dummy_type { };

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  cout << std::boolalpha;
  cout << is_hashable<int>::value << endl;
  cout << is_hashable<dummy_type>::value << endl;

  test<set<int>>();
  test<set<dummy_type>>();
}
```

The output should be similar to

```
true
false
void test() [with T = std::unordered_set<int, std::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, std::allocator<int> >]
void test() [with T = std::set<dummy_type, std::less<dummy_type>, std::allocator<dummy_type> >]
```

**Edit**:
`is_hashable` specialization can also be done without the use of `void_t`, like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_hashable<T, decltype(std::hash<T>{},void())> : std::true_type { };
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I need and even more

Answer (score 5):

If you have a `is_hashable<T>` type trait (e.g. your `HasHash`), then you can use [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional), like so:

```
template <typename T>
std::conditional<is_hashable<T>::value, std::unordered_set<T>, std::set<T>>::type
```

or if you're using C++17, it could be simplified to:

```
template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_hashable_v = is_hashable<T>::value;

template <typename T>
std::conditional_t<is_hashable_v<T>, std::unordered_set<T>, std::set<T>>;
```

(assuming you've also implemented the `_v` version of the trait).

For some additional discussion regarding determining hashability, this is also interesting:

[Check if type is hashable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753997/check-if-type-is-hashable)

here on the site.

Comment: Thank you, but I am really new at metaprogramming and don't know how to implement this to my problem. I need to make a class with some container in it, but there is no way to use the both `std::set` and `std::unodered_set`. And how can I use `std::conditional` to solve this problem?

Comment: Oh, I forget to mention that type `T` might don't have both operators `==` and (`<` or `>`). For this type I need to use `std::unordered_set<T*>`, and I am afraid that `std::conditional`  might not help me.